# kotlin, .Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0 , Switch from Activity to View with inflater

Tags: android, kotlin

i want to call view from activity, and i have a class which have inflater functions. but i cant use it

it says cant find class 
Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0

MainActivity

```
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

            menu_button.setOnClickListener {
                v:View-> val view_menu = View_menu(this, "root_layout")
                if(view_menu != null) view_menu.removeFromContainer()
                view_menu.initInterface()
                view_menu.addContentToContainer()
```

View_menu

```
open class View_menu : _View, View.OnClickListener {

    init{
        mContent.close_button.setOnClickListener (this)
        mContent.question_button.setOnClickListener (this)
        mContent.cooper_button.setOnClickListener (this)
        mContent.privacy_button.setOnClickListener (this)

    }

    constructor(activity: Activity, containerName: String) : super(activity, containerName, "view_menu")
```

and here's _View class

```
open class View_menu : _View, View.OnClickListener {

    init{
        mContent.close_button.setOnClickListener (this)
        mContent.question_button.setOnClickListener (this)
        mContent.cooper_button.setOnClickListener (this)
        mContent.privacy_button.setOnClickListener (this)

    }

    constructor(activity: Activity, containerName: String) : super(activity, containerName, "view_menu")
```

and ive got error from

```
  constructor(activity: Activity, containerName: String) : super(activity, containerName, "view_menu")
```

i want switch from Activity to View

Comment: i found the error, the layout name was wrong